# QAbstractItemModel::endInsertRows: Invalid index run time error

Tags: c++, qt4

Greeting, everyone, I'm currently using QTableView to build my c++ GUI project.
However, when I'm doing adding row into the table, the run time error which is QAbstractItemModel::endInsertRows:  Invalid index  occurs.
This problem only occurs when I'm selecting last row in my QTableView, is there any solution for this problem? Thanks~

```
bool TableModel::insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index)
{
    Q_UNUSED(index);
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), position, position+rows-1);
    endInsertRows();
    return true;
}
```

submit button click slot:

```
void MainWindow::on_submitButton_clicked()
{
    reminder node;
    node.setNote(ui->noteInput->toPlainText().toStdString());
    node.setDate(ui->dateInput->text().toStdString());
    QModelIndex index = mymodel->index(0, 0, QModelIndex());
    mymodel->insertRows(0, 1, index);
    mymodel->setData(index, node, Qt::EditRole);
    ui->tableView->scrollToBottom();
 }
```

setData:

```
 bool TableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const reminder &value, int role)
 {

       if (role == Qt::EditRole) {
                aList.insert(aList.getLength()+1, value); /* aList is a linked List to store reminder */
                emit(dataChanged(index, index));
                aList.saveList(listFile);
                return true;
        }

    return false;
  }
```

//edit

thanks everyone, i already solve this question by moving my insert list function into insertRows that, TQVM

Comment: Post your relevant code.

Comment: This is not a forum. If you have found the answer, you should answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone, i already solve this question by moving my insert list function into insertRows there, TQVM